# String include weird behavior

Tags: ruby, string

I was doing a code golf (use the minimum number of characters) and I had the following working Python solution. I was trying to shorten my code by re-writing it to Ruby but my Ruby code would always print `false`.

The code had to read two strings, to ignore the case and to tell whether it was possible to obtain one string by rotating the other string. The output had to be either `true` or `false`. Do you have any idea what I did wrong in Ruby?

Python 3 (64 characters) - Works

```
a=input().lower()
b=input().lower()
print(str(a in 2*b).lower())
```

Ruby (47 characters) - Always prints "false"

```
a=gets.upcase
b=gets.upcase
p (b*2).include? a
```

---

With the examples I can think of, the Ruby code works correctly, but for some reason, it didn't work on the code golf site (codingame.com, the problem was proposed by user "10100111001").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby `gets` includes the `\n` at the end. You'd have to `.chomp` it away before doing anything.

```
a=gets.chomp.upcase
b=gets.chomp.upcase
p (b*2).include? a
```

By the way, this is not the right way to "tell whether it was possible to obtain one string by rotating the other string", it only partially solves the problem, hope you know that.

Comment: This makes the ruby solution 59 characters long, but still better than python.

Comment: This might help: `def f;gets.chomp.upcase;end;a=f;p !!(f*2)[a]`, 45 chars long.

Comment: With strings "abc" and "bcda" you're going to have a false positive.

Comment: @steenslag That's not a false positive: `"abc"` is contained in `"bcdabcda"`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yes it is contained, but not obtained. Ah, may be i'm biased: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/detect-rotated-strings

Comment: @steenslag Oh, I see what you mean. I did not even think about the actual problem and just focused on OP's code since it was out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @steenslag We can assert the strings lengths are equal.